# Displaying custom messages on windows start up

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is there a way to display different messages on windows start up? I found this: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15771/display-a-text-message-during-bootup-of-windows-7/ which shows how to display the same message every time. 
 I am trying to create a script that will display a different message each time windows boots up, but i have not had much luck  with it.

So far I have this:

```
Dim message 
message = Array("message 1","message 2","message 3","message 4","message 5","message 6","message 7")

Randomize
MsgBox message (Int(Rnd*7))
```

but this needs to be triggered manually each time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Lets start with the basic.  What sort of script is this exactly?  I don't visit `HowToGeek` can't stand their unprofessionalism.

Comment: How-To-Geek doesn't describe using code. Where did you come up with this and where are you trying to run it from?

Comment: I came up with it on my own, had some minor VB experience. The idea is that I give this script to a friend and tell him how to 'install' it. After he does that, every time he starts his computer a message will pop up(was his girlfriend's idea, trying to display some funny messages when he starts his computer).